# Problem with generic array copying

Tags: java, generics, classcastexception

### Goal

---

I am making a Java class that will give enhanced usability to arrays, such as `add`, `remove`, and `contains` methods. I figured the best solution is to make a class (called `ArrayPP`) that has a type parameter `T`. This way, the user can interact with the `ArrayPP` object as easily as they can with an array of the same type.

### Problem

---

I quickly found that such methods as `add` will require the creation of a separate array, and end up changing the target array `t` from an array of `T`s into an array of `Object`s. As you may guess, this totally destroys the usability, and when I try to do something like

```
File[] f = new File[0];
ArrayPP<File> appF = new ArrayPP(f);
appF.add(saveFile);
f = appF.toArray();
```

the program throws

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.io.File;
```

because the `add` method has to change the array into an array of `Object`s, as the Java compiler won't let you make a generic array (`T[] t = new T[0];` is bad, but `T[] t = (T[]) new Object[0];` is okay). I know from line-by-line debugging that the above code keeps the array `t`, in this case, as a n array of `File`s UNTIL the 4th line of the `add` method is called. **Does anyone have a solution that will keep the array `t` being an array of `T`s and not an array of `Object`s?**

### Sample Code

---

Below is a VERY watered-down version of my class.

```
public class ArrayPP<T>
{
  T[] t;

  /**
   * Creates a new Array++ to manage the given array.
   * <h3>Analogy:</h3>
   * <tt>ArrayPP&lt;String&gt; s = new ArrayPP(args);</tt><br/>
   * is analogous to<br/>
   * <tt>String s[] = args;</tt>
   * @param array The array to be managed
   */
  public ArrayPP(T[] array)
  {
    t = array;
  }

  /**
   * Appends a value to the end of the array
   * @param val the value to be appended
   * @return the resulting array.
   */
  public ArrayPP add(T val)
  {
    T[] temp = (T[]) new Object[t.length + 1];
    System.arraycopy(t, 0, temp, 0, t.length);
    temp[temp.length - 1] = val;
    t = (T[])temp;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the array at the core of this wrapper
   * @return the array at the core of this wrapper
   */
  public T[] toArray()
  {
    return t;
  }
}
```

### Possible Solution?

---

After looking at other questions about generic arrays, I think I have a solution:

Instead of

```
  /**
   * Appends a value to the end of the array
   * @param val the value to be appended
   * @return the resulting array.
   */
  public ArrayPP add(T val)
  {
    T[] temp = (T[]) new Object[t.length + 1];
    System.arraycopy(t, 0, temp, 0, t.length);
    temp[temp.length - 1] = val;
    t = (T[])temp;
    return this;
  }
```

will this work?

```
  /**
   * Appends a value to the end of the array
   * @param val the value to be appended
   * @return the resulting array.
   */
  public ArrayPP<T> add(T val)
  {
    t = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(t, t.length + 1);
    t[t.length - 1] = val;
    return this;
  }
```

Comment: Umm, that class already exists ... it's called `java.util.ArrayList`.

Comment: ArrayList doesn't have all the capabilities I'm looking for

Comment: what capabilities doesn't `ArrayList` have that you need?  Can't you just create a class that extends `ArrayList`?

Comment: If you want, my code will be available in open source. Send an email to me at supuhstar0@gmail.com if you want me to explain, in-depth, why I must make an entirely new class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle you can't easily create arrays of a generic type (or type variable).

If you have a class object, you can use reflection, or if you have an example array, the methods in the `java.util.Arrays` class to create a (longer/shorter) copy. But it is not elegant either way.

The ArrayList class internally simply uses an `Object[]` to store its elements, and converts only on get/set/add/toArray.
What would your class do better than ArrayList?

---

Edit:

I would recommend either simply delegate to an ArraysList, or do the implementation like ArrayList does, using an `Object[]` internally, and converting on output where necessary.

If you really want to have an array of the right type internally, it is possible - but it gets ugly, as I said.

The `add` method is still the easiest case:

```
  /**
   * Appends a value to the end of the array
   * @param val the value to be appended
   * @return the resulting array.
   */
  public ArrayPP add(T val)
  {
     T[] temp = Arrays.copyOf(t, t.length+1);
     temp[t.length] = val;
     t = temp;
     return this;
  }
```

When you want to add in the middle or remove, you'll have to combine this with your arraycopy.

Comment: it implements such interfaces as Comparable and has methods that complexly and intelligently remove different types of objects. Again, what I show is only what needs to be seen for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Is there some reason the built-it `List<T>` class(es) can't do what you need?  As in:

```
String[] theArray = {"a", "b", "c"};
List<String> theList = Arrays.asList(theArray);
```

Comment: Yes, there is. This class has methods that are implemented from interfaces such as Comparable, but they aren't shown here. My problem is with methods that change the array's size such as `add`, `remove`, `insert`, etc.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but then couldn't you extend ArrayList (for instance), and add your additional methods there (or override the existing ones that you want to change)?

Comment: I suppose I could, but I don't want to. You see, my aim is not to REPLACE any classes, but to make my own. For instance, I don't want my class to have an `asList` method, because I want it to be entirely arrays.

Comment: (There's a name for this: its called "NIH Syndrome".  If left untreated it can develop into full blown "Custom Framework" disease.)

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayPP(T[] array)
    componentClass = array.getClass().getComponentClass();

T[] newArray(int length)
    return Array.newInstance(componentClass, length)
```

Comment: my problem is with the add method

Comment: `T[] temp = newArray( t.length + 1 )`